# Comments in Rpres

Tags: r, comments, rpres

I'm trying to put a comment in my Rpres script, but I don't want that comment to appear in the final presentation. I know that in an R script, the comments are expressed by #comment. But how it would be in Rpres?

For example, for a specific slide:

## Title of slide:

````
```{r}
 vector <- c(1,2,4)
 dataframe <- data[data$line == 4,]
 table <- table(dataframe$line2)
 ```
````

I want to add a comment here about a code line (this comment would be visible only for me in my Rpres script, but not on the presentation display).

Then I explain the results (this part would be on the presentation display).

Is there a special key like % or # that would make that work?

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way of doing this, what I found to be fairly generic is the following format:

```
[//]: # ("this is just a comment")
```